# Github repository visibility issue

Tags: git, github, repository, github-pages, visibility

I changed the visibility of my repository from private to public. I am having difficulties changing it back to private hours later. I keep getting this message "Sorry, repository visibility cannot be changed at this time. A previous visibility change is still in progress.  ".
How do i go about this

I have tried changing the visibility back to private from the settings tab

Comment: I'm guessing you simply have to wait for the previous visibility change to go through before you can start a new one.